# KIS 2010 on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus

Is it possible to install KIS 2010 on windows server 2008 R2

Comment: KIS = Kaspersky Internet Security?

Comment: Version 8 is fully compatible.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking Kaspersky Internet Security 2010 the answer is no. Just tried it on a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine and it comes up with an application error box saying 'This application could not be installed. Current operating system is not supported.'

KIS is Kaspersky's consumer product, you want to be looking at either the **Kaspersky Small Office Security** bundle, or **Kaspersky Anti-virus for File Server** or **Kaspersky Anti-virus for Windows Servers Enterprise Edition** (both of which come under the Kaspersky Business Space Security suite).

Answer (score 0):

Probably but you'd need to check the license with Kaspersky and also if there is a better suited Server-based product.